# Comonads and the category of Sets

Tags: ct.category-theory

In [Vicary's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0711), after eq 15, he talks about how the category of internal comonoids  $C_\times$ has many properties of the category of sets.  We know that a comonad on a category has the same axioms as the internal comonoids (copy, delete etc).   Can we construct a category with the properties of the categories of sets just from the a comonad on any category?  Since there are many comonads out there, what would it mean to build up these mini "categories of sets" in CAT, starting at 1,2,3 and onwards with other, more complex categories?

Comment: Keep in mind that Vicary is working in the setting where $\mathbf{C}$ is a *symmetric* monoidal category. A comonad is a comonoid in an endofunctor category, which is merely monoidal, not symmetric monoidal. So, for example, the product = composite of two comonads is not a comonad generally.

Comment: So, by composite do you mean a cartesian product, or perhaps the monoidal product $A \otimes B$, is not a comonad (where $A,B$ comonads or as, you say, comonoids in an endofunctor category)?  Is there a way to restrict the types of comonads so that we have a symmetric product?

Comment: Todd, I think I have been searching for symmetric monoidal endofunctor categories for a while.  (not knowing it, of course).  I have dreamed of replacing Hilb and its sym-monoidal structure with the general notion of monad.  Any thoughts you have on symmetric monoidal endofunctor categories would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having difficulty formulating a reply; I don't want to toss random ideas around. It might help if I knew what you needed this for. I also find parts of your post puzzling: you seem to start off by asking about categories of comonads (plural), but then ask "can we construct a category with the properties of the categories of sets just from the a comonad" (singular). One final remark: it's not clear that Vicary meant anything very precise when he likens a category of (cocommutative) comonoids (in a general $C$) to the category of sets, although the analogy is not weak for certain $C$.

Comment: Yes, I'm all over the place here.  Sorry about that.  I'm working in physics and I want an epistemic model that is rooted in monads (like the Giry Monad and Vicary's paper).  I want to get rid of any special underlying category like Hilb (or MEAS as in Giry).  Instead, you just have arbitrary categories as apparatuses and a monad on the category is a theory of your interactions with the apparatus so far.  An update to your theory is an experiment and this is a natural transformation.  I believe I need to work in a functor category, one that is symmetric monoidal.

Comment: Hey, I put together a (hopefully) more [succinct question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177663/symmetric-monoidal-dagger-endofunctor-categories).

Comment: "One final remark: it's not clear that Vicary meant anything very precise when he likens a category of (cocommutative) comonoids (in a general C) to the category of sets".   Knowing him, probably just that it's cartesian.