# symmetric monoidal dagger endofunctor categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Take an arbitrary category $C$, and consider $End(C)$, any endofunctor category consisting of some or all endofunctors of $C$.
I have several related questions:

1. What restrictions must we impose on the base category $C$ such that $End(C)$ has a symmetric monoidal product?
2. What restrictions must we impose on the functors $F \in Ob(End(C))$ for $End(C)$ to have a symmetric monoidal product?

I am also interested in the same two questions when we are interested in dagger compactness, ie, there is an endo functor $\dagger : End(C) \rightarrow End(C)$, where $\dagger$ is identity on objects but flips all the natural transformations in $End(C)$, ie all its arrows.  $\dagger \circ \dagger = Id_{End(C)}$.

I am trying to build Abramsky, Coecke's [semantic category](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0402130v5.pdf) for quantum protocols (also [Selinger's construction](http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/dagger.pdf)) in terms endofunctor categories on arbitrary base categories.

Comment: I would like to point out that with a dagger structure on $End(C)$, we have a category where every object is a monad and has a twin comanad, which together form a Frobenius monad.

Comment: Sorry, not every object is a monad, but when you do have a monad, you also have a frobenius monad.

Comment: I'm not sure about the dagger part, but any time you have a category of functors Fun(C,D) you can endow it with the Day convolution product. In your case C=D and you don't need any restrictions on the types of functors. You just need C to be a monoidal category (symmetric if you want the Day product symmetric). See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130616/reference-for-lax-monoidal-functors-monoids-under-day-convolution

Comment: @DavidWhite: Day convolution needs colimits with distribute over the tensor product.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks. I was unaware of that, since I always work in a closed monoidal setting. But it's good to know there is in fact an extra hypothesis needed.